# How to have a checkbox for readmefile at the finished page in InnoSetup

Tags: inno-setup

I want to have a checkbox at the finishpage of InnoSetup to open or not the readme file. I try something like this (like it's explain here [flag postinstall](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=runsection) but it seems doesn't works:

```
Name: "StartAfterInstall"; Description: Display the PDF Readme File; Languages: english
Filename: "{app}\readme.pdf"; Tasks: StartAfterInstall; Flags: shellexec postinstall runasoriginaluser; Languages: not French
```

It propose only to launch the program. Is there a way to do this without use the [code] section in Inno Setup or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this task simply mark your readme file entry in your [`[Files]`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection) section with the [`isreadme`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection&anchor=isreadme) flag and let the Inno Setup do the rest for you:

```
[Files]
Source: "Readme.txt"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: isreadme
```

The [`isreadme`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection&anchor=isreadme) flag is described as (emphasized by me):

> File is the "README" file. Only one file in an installation can have
>   this flag. **When a file has this flag, the user will asked if he/she
>   would like to view the README file after the installation has
>   completed.** If Yes is chosen, Setup will open the file, using the
>   default program for the file type. For this reason, the README file
>   should always end with an extension like .txt, .wri, or .doc.
>
> Note that if Setup has to restart the user's computer (as a result of
>   installing a file with the flag restartreplace or if the AlwaysRestart
>   [Setup] section directive is yes), the user will not be given an
>   option to view the README file.

Comment: Ok. I do that but it seems dont work : just put that for test `Source: "D:\...\lisez-moi.doc"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: isreadme` ... but I have just the checkbox of launching program

Comment: That is known to work. The example from my post creates a check box *View readme.txt* on the final page. Try it with a brand new project, or try the [`Example1.iss`](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/is-5_5_5/Examples/Example1.iss) example from the shipped examples.

Comment: That's work with example, but not with my iss file... strange. And over that, apparently all the setup's readme are in pdf in my bussiness... so i think i will try another way... another idea ?

Comment: Replace a *.txt file with some *.pdf in that example and you'll see it working. I can't tell you why it doesn't work in your production script without seeing it. Also note that only one file can be marked by `isreadme` flag. I answered this way since you mentioned that you are about to open only one file.

Comment: Ok, sorry it's working well.. pfewww. I've forget to update a path for ouput :/ sorry. Yes i see i can only use this flags one time... so i can't use different file for different language i think ? Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can. That's just the place for the `Languages` parameter. You will just specify more entries with this flag, one for each language (or group of languages separated by spaces).